# Unable to run Parse Cloud Code on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want to run Parse Cloud Code on Android and for this purpose I follow the instructions provided in the [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide). I try to execute the following code:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
  void done(String result, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // result is "Hello world!"
    }
  }
});
```

I get a compile-time error, stating:

*'done(String, ParseException)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.parse.FunctionCallback' clashes with 'done(T, ParseException)' in 'com.parse.FunctionCallback'; attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('packageLocal'); was 'public'*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. There should be a 'public' access modifier on the done method.

```
...
public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
...
```

Now everything works fine.